# Are two dot products of a random variable vector independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, vectors, finite-fields, independence

Let $w,v$ be two different vectors in the finite vector space $Z_p^m$ over $Z_p$ where $p$ is prime. Let $u$ be a vector chosen uniformly at random from $Z_p^m$. Are the random variables $u \cdot w$ and $u \cdot v$ independent (the dot product calculated over $Z_p$)? If not, can we estimate their covariance somehow?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The dot products are also over $Z_p$?

Comment: @leonbloy Yes, they are

Comment: In general, they are not independent (take $w = \alpha v$ for scalar $\alpha).

Comment: @Batman, what if the vectors are linearly independent?

Comment: How do you define the covariance of random variables that are not real valued? I mean, this is roughly like: A basket contains 20 oranges, 12 bananas and 17 apples. Alice and Bob pick one fruit randomly. What is the covariance of their choices?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen They are real valued here? I don't understand.

Comment: Dot product is in $\Bbb{Z}_p$ here. But $\Bbb{Z}_p$ is not a subset of $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I'm just treating it as a real number from 0 to p-1